# WCF Test Client shows IMetadataExchange

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008-sp1

When I use the WCF Test Client, it shows an IMetadataExchange end point, even if I don't have one defined. However that endpoint also has an error indicating it can't talk to the endpoint. I've tested this on a few applications and it happens with all of them:

'The contract 'IMetadataExchange' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract.'

The funny thing is that this client belongs to Visual Studio 2008, and I presume the client app.config is generated by VS in the background somewhere, then uses it to attempt to talk to the service.

Any ideas? I'm using VSTS Developer with SP1 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [walk through](http://blogs.msdn.com/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2008/08/28/tips-for-wcf-tools-in-vs2008-sp1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you have the BizTalk LOB adapter pack installed. In my case unfortunately, since I am using those adapters, I can't comment out the section as shown in the walk through so its something I have to live with (in any case the WCF test client is not useful for services that use complex input and output types)

Answer (score 0):

Ric's link was damn close... I had seen that link earlier in my search for an answer but had disregarded it because I didn't have anything related to Biztalk installed. It turns out it is actually the Azure .Net Services SDK that caused the rogue entry in machine.config. It relates to some Microsoft.ServiceBus dll's that I am sure were inherited from Biztalk Services anyway, so the Biztalk link was very close.

Answer (score 0):

If You Have Installed Windows Azure SDk on your Machine, Please Uninstall,and Run your test Client.It Will Run Perfectlly